# The new account created has no funds and cannot be transferred unless `--allow-unfunded-recipient` is added

Tags: web3.js, transfer

##### Problem

When I create a new account using the following two methods, there is no fund by default and cannot be transferred.

1. use the `@solana/web3.js`

```
import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";

const keypair = Keypair.generate();

console.log(`The public key is: `, keypair.publicKey.toBase58());
```

Error message：

```
      throw new SendTransactionError(
            ^


SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Transaction results in an account (1) with insufficient funds for rent
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (D:\web3_code\solana_learn\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:5921:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Connection.sendRawTransaction (D:\web3_code\solana_learn\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:5880:20)
    at Connection.sendTransaction (D:\web3_code\solana_learn\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:5868:12)
    at sendAndConfirmTransaction (D:\web3_code\solana_learn\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\utils\send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:35:21)    
    at <anonymous> (d:\web3_code\solana_learn\solanatransfer.ts:50:53) {
  logs: [
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.18.2
```

2. use solana cli

```
solana-keygen new --force
solana transfer HV4egCuRfqnoGipQxVGRLLVRRfbmPH6EWdxKDKdyLktg 0.1
```

Error message：

```
Error: The recipient address (HV4egCuRfqnoGipQxVGRLLVRRfbmPH6EWdxKDKdyLktg) is not funded. Add `--allow-unfunded-recipient` to complete the transfer
```

##### Proposed Solution

1. use solana cli

```
solana transfer --allow-unfunded-recipient 9w4egkmzj6Byop2iEA8ecP3m65zVn9ayNFFD1DNSdNPA 0.1
```

2. use the `@solana/web3.js`
   I don't know how to deal with this problem, like I don't know why the newly created account is unfunded and can't be transferred

Comment: Your first code block (web3js one) doesn't throw the error that you're showing after it. Please update your question to include the code that is actually throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Keypair generation does not create an account. You can even generate a keypair using pen and paper, but it does not mean that that will be published on blockchain.

Just airdrop some sols to create an account.